# Subtraction in Java value shortage

Tags: java, arrays

I encounter a difficult problem. I am looking for a suggestion how to approach in this problem. I have three field in my dataset. I want to perform a subtraction.The problem is like that.

```
 Time(s)    a      x
  1         0.1    0.2
  2                0.4
  3                0.6
  4                0.7
  5         0.2    0.9
```

I need to perform a subtraction from (a-x). But the method of subtraction is like that at time 1s `a` has value 0.1. The operation will be (0.1-0.2) 1st iteration. `2nd iteration (0.1-0.4)`.  `3rd iteration (0.1-0.6)`.`4th iteration (0.1-0.7)` But in 2nd iteration it will be `(0.2-0.9)`.

This is my problem statement. I want to write down this code in `Java`. `I don't need Java code`. I can write it down myself. I need a suggestion how to proceed in this approach?. One thought is that `creating array for each variable`. But then stuck on loop. How the loop iterated? It is clear array a is static until it get next value, which is available at Time 5s.

Comment: This isn't a very difficult problem to find a solution for, the difficult part is more selecting the one that is best. To get you started, for `a` you can create an array that is filled with the same value until it is changed so that you get two equally sized arrays.

Comment: How does the arrays look like? Can you be clear on your input?

Comment: If the `a` and `x` arrays are different sized, you can consider using nested loops.

Comment: What form does your input have? CSV file or what?

Comment: @lexicore text file.

Comment: @EllenaMori text file in what format? Are they comma separated values (CSV)? space separated values? tab separated? any-whitespace separated?

Comment: @xtratic They are space separated values.

Comment: @EllenaMori My updated answer should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how large is your input file:

1. If the dataset fits into memory load it as either 2 separate array or as one array of `Row` objects with `a` and `x` as fields. After that it's simple iteration remembering what was the last row that contained `a` to use it when `a` is missing.
2. If the dataset is large it's better to read it using [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and only remember the last encountered `a` and `x`. This will greatly reduce the memory consumption and would be the preferred approach.

Comment: My data file has 100000 data.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` changes every 4 numbers you can use `time's / 4 + 1` to get value from small array of `a`.

If  `a` changes not every 4 numbers, then I suggest to use full array filled with same values.

Comment: No my time does not change in every 4 number. It changes arbitrarily. Some time in 4 number some time 10 number etc. What do you mean by `full array filled with same values.` Did you mean to full array a with 0.0 values?

Answer (score 0):

*Now that I see you're not using a database and just reading from a file, maybe try this*

Just keep the old value of `a` until a new value can overwrite it.
This is memory efficient since it parses line by line.

```
public static List<Double> parseFile(String myFile) throws IOException {

    List<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));) {
        b.readLine(); // ** skip header?

        String line;
        Integer time = null;
        Double a = null;
        Double x = null;
        for (int lineNum = 0; (line = b.readLine()) != null; lineNum++) {

            // ** split the data on any-and-all-whitespace
            final String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
            if (data.length != 3)
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid data format on line " + lineNum);

            try {
                time = Integer.valueOf(data[0]);
                if (!data[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
                    a = Double.valueOf(data[1]);
                }
                if (!data[2].trim().isEmpty()) {
                    x = Double.valueOf(data[2]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't parse line " + lineNum, e);
            }

            if (a == null || x == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Values not initialized at line " + lineNum);
            }

            results.add(Double.valueOf(a.doubleValue() - x.doubleValue()));
        }
    }
    // ** finished parsing file, return results
    return results;
}
```

Comment: `getAatTime` and `getXatTime`  Can you write down this two function. This two are not very clear to me. Yes a is null at the blank spaces.

Comment: @EllenaMori I have updated my answer now that I know this is just being parsed from a file.